# How to handle release year difference in movie recommendation

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, doc2vec

I have been part of the movie recommendation project. We have developed a doc2vec model using gensim.
You can have a look at gensim documentation if needed.
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar

Trained the model and when i took top 10 similar movies for a film based on cast it gives way back old movies with release_yr as (1960, 1950, ...). So i have tried including the release_yr as a parameter to gensim model but still it shows me old movies. How can i solve this release_yr difference? When I see top10 recommendations for a film I need those movies whose release_yr difference is less (like past 10 years movies not more than that). How can i do that?

code for doc2vec model

```
def d2v_doc(titles_df):
    tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=_d, tags=[str(titles_df['id_titles'][i])]) for i, _d in enumerate(titles_df['doc'])]
    model_d2v = Doc2Vec(vector_size=300,min_count=10, dm=1)
    model_d2v.build_vocab(tagged_data)
    model_d2v.train(tagged_data,epochs=100,total_examples=model_d2v.corpus_count)
    return model_d2v
```

titles_df dataframe contains columns(id_titles, title, release_year, actors, director, writer, doc)

```
col_names = ['actors', 'director','writer','release_year']
titles_df['doc'] = titles_df[col_names].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1).str.split()
```

Code for Top 10 similar movies

```
def titles_lookup(similar_doc,titles_df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(similar_doc, columns =['id_titles', 'simialrity'])
    df = pd.merge(df, titles_df[['id_titles','title','release_year']],on='id_titles',how='left')
    print(df)


def demo_d2v_title(model,titles_df, id_titles):
    similar_doc = model.docvecs.most_similar(id_titles)
    titles_lookup(similar_doc,titles_df)

def demo(model,titles_df):
    print('hunt for red october')
    demo_d2v_title(model,titles_df, 'tt0099810')
```

The output for Top 10 similar movies for film - **"hunt for red october"**

```
   id_titles    similarity               title             release_year
0  tt0105112    0.541722             Patriot Games           1992.0
1  tt0267626    0.524941       K19: The Widowmaker           2002.0
2  tt0112740    0.496758              Crimson Tide           1995.0
3  tt0052151    0.471951       Run Silent Run Deep           1958.0
4  tt1922685    0.464007                   Phantom           2013.0
5  tt0164184    0.462187      The Sum of All Fears           2002.0
6  tt0058962    0.459588      The Bedford Incident           1965.0
7  tt0109444    0.456760  Clear and Present Danger           1994.0
8  tt0063121    0.455807         Ice Station Zebra           1968.0
9  tt0146309    0.452572             Thirteen Days           2001.0
```

you can see from the output that i'm still getting old movies. Please help me how to solve that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hows your feature importance graphs ?

Comment: what do you mean by that? By the way we didnot plot any graphs

Comment: Your release_year feature might not be on top, hence no improvement. Maybe you can try assigning custom weight to the features, but that's a problem in itself.

Comment: @YashKumarAtri can you please tell me how to assign custom weights to gensim model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Doc2Vec` only knows text-similarity; it doesn't have the idea of other fields.

So if you want to discard matches according to some criteria other than text-similarity, that's only represented external to the `Doc2Vec` model, you'll have to do that in a separate step.

So, you could use `.most_similar()` with a `topn=len(model.docvecs)` parameter - to get back *all* moviews, ranked. Then, filter that result-set by discarding any whose year is too-far from your desired year. Then, trim that result-set to the top N that you really want.